# Number of terms in the expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

The number of terms in the expansion of  $$\left(x+y+z+w\right)^{10}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients

Comment: Linking related questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635551/number-of-terms-in-expansion-of-1xyz5), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484908/find-the-coefficient-of-w3x5z2-in-the-expansion-of-wxyz10), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822137/the-expansion-of-abcd20).

Comment: Also related to [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656258/how-many-ways-to-put-20-things-to-different-4-boxes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each term is of the form $x^a y^b z^c w^d$ with $a+b+c+d=10$.

We have four elements, $x,y,z,w$, and we need to choose $10$ with repetition ignoring order.

This is called combination with repetition, or "multiset coefficient".

The required number is $\left(\dbinom{4}{10}\right) = \dbinom{4+10-1}{4-1} = \dbinom{13}3 = 286$.

Answer (score -1):

We can start by considering smaller values for the exponent and seeing if we notice a pattern:

\begin{align}(x+y+z+w)^1&\text{ has } 4\text{ terms}\\
(x+y+z+w)^2&\text{ has } 10\text{ terms}\\
(x+y+z+w)^3&\text{ has } 20\text{ terms}\\
(x+y+z+w)^4&\text{ has } 35\text{ terms}\end{align}

These are [triangle numbers](https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C10%2C20%2C35&language=english&go=Search), shunted by $1$, with the number of terms in $(x+y+z+w)^n$ calculated by $$\frac {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}$$

Therefore, we have $(x+y+z+w)^{10}$ having $$\frac{11\times12\times13}6=286\text{ terms}$$

Comment: solution is easy to understand but how you conclude the number of terms for 2, 3 and 4 power of expansion, as it is very tedious job or do you have any other approach?

Comment: @user146551 Personally, I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) for speed, however you can calculate them by hand - you square the expression, and then you just need to multiply the result by $(x+y+z+w)$ to get each subsequent exponent